# Inequality $a^{\tan(b)}+b^{\tan(c)}+c^{\tan(a)}\leq 3(\frac{1}{3})^{\tan(\frac{1}{3})}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, exponentiation

Hi I have a new problem this is the following :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ then we have :
>   $$a^{\tan(b)}+b^{\tan(c)}+c^{\tan(a)}\leq 3(\frac{1}{3})^{\tan(\frac{1}{3})}$$

I know that $f(x)=x^{\tan(x)}$ is convex on the interval $[0;1]$ but I think it doesn't help at all .

I try also rearrangement inequality but it fails .

If you have hints it would be nice tahnks a lot .

Comment: problem source please.

Comment: I wonder why this question was reopened. There is no context for the inequality, or any motivation why it should be true. The question will never be improved because the user account does no longer exist.